# Azure Functions Runtime

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

Installed the Azure Functions Runtime as per the instructions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-functions/functions-runtime-install

Configured all the things including the SQL etc correctly.

After doing that when to the https://localhost and tried to create a new Azure functions App.

When trying to create the Azure Functions App, it fails. I verified the Azure Functions Host Activation Service and the Docker Service are running.

Below is the error when trying to create the functions App from the local box:

[image]

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue with the latest Azure Functions Runtime (Preview) installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check in the following Windows Event log for any errors on the Functions Management Role:
**Microsoft-Windows-FunctionsRuntime/Operational**

If you don't see any information there, please follow this instructions to capture a trace for the **FunctionsAPI** website with status code 400-999:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Answer (score 2):

For me, this issue was actually caused by WebDAV handler not allowing PUT verb. After I allowed all verbs in IIS for FunctionsAPI, it works like a charm.

You can use F12 in your web browser to help identify the root cause of the issue by going through the steps of creating a new function app.